# Hibernate validate dosent work without breakpoint stops on debug mode

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-validator

I have the follow code that call by rest service:

```
 Validator validator = beanValidationController.createValidator();
 Set<ConstraintViolation<MyBean>> violations = validator.validate(myBean);
 //Interate violations and return messages
```

If call the rest that call this code, the 'violations' are empty, but if put the breakpoint in first line ( Validator validator = beanValidationController.createValidator();) and break, the 'violations' is not empty. I try put Thread.sleep(); before code but dosent work.

I use Red Hat JBoss EAP 6.1+ with jdk 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I vaguely remember we had some bug a while ago related to the iteration order of sets. This kind of error often manifests itself in the behavior you describe. Can you try with the latest EAP 6.4 and HV 4.3.2.Final?